# malloc on Arbitrary Type

Tags: c++, malloc

Suppose I have a type `MyType` whose constructor takes a `std::string` as an argument (not default-constructable).

I wish to then call,

```
MyType* arr = (MyType*) malloc(N * sizeof(MyType));
```

and then use pointer arithmetic to do something like,

```
std::string str("pi");
*(arr + 31415926) = std::move(MyType(str));
```

This is triggering a `segfault` and my understanding is that the `malloc`'d memory has no constructed objects, and the `std::move` assignment is being called on a non-existent object.

What do I need to do to most efficiently move objects into the array? I would rather not resort to `std::vector<MyType>` and `std::vector<MyType>::reserve()`

a) Because **different** parts of the array are going to be read from/written to by different `std::thread`s

b) I would like to understand dynamic memory management.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: If you use malloc/free in C++ code then you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: Use `new[]` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: Is `N` greater than `31415926`?

Comment: @RSahu Yep, no risk of accessing outside the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving aside the issue of `malloc`/`free` vs. `new char[]`/`delete[]`, you can construct arrays in uninitialized storage with **placement new**. The syntax is

```
new(address) classname(parameters);
```

In your case:

```
// Mighty big "array" you have there...
new(arr + 31415926) MyType(std::move(some_existing_mytype_object));
```

Note that you will have to call the constructor manually (and not use `delete`), as in

```
arr[31415926].~MyType();
```

to destroy it later. **Be aware that doing this sort of thing requires great care**, particularly wrt exception safety, and that you probably **should not do it.** `std::vector` does this internally so you don't have to.

Comment: Thank you. I then call `free` once all objects are destroyed? Also, if different parts of `std::vector` are being written/read by different `std::thread`s (no overlap) but the size of the vector never changes, would that be safe?

Comment: If you `malloc`ed the memory, yes. Is is more usual to use `new char[]` and `delete[]`, though. Be very, very, *very* careful with this, and please consider other ways of doing what you want to do. It is rarely a good idea to do manual memory management in C++.

Comment: Yes, if you have a vector of static size and different areas of it are written to by different threads, that is safe. It may lead to cache ping pong (and therefore performance degradation) in some circumstances, but that's a problem you'd have to deal with anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You are right - `malloc` doesn't call constructor(and `free` won't call destructor later), so u have to call it manually or use placement new on allocated memory(don't forget to call destructor before freeing memory). 
Becouse of issues I mentioned before, you should use `new` and `delete` if you can.